# Firebase not-equal queries not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read the latest [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html) which reports firebase now supports ***not-equal queries***. However, it is not working on this android code snippet and I am getting ***Unresolved reference: where*** error when using where.

```
private fun getAllContacts() {
    val currentUserPhoneCredential = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber!!

    firestore.collection("Contacts")
         //getting unresolved reference when using where
        .where("phoneNumber", "!=", currentUserPhoneCredential)
        .get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
        for (doc in querySnapshot) {

            val user = doc.toObject(User::class.java)
            
            contactsList.add(user)
            contactsNames.add(user.name!!)

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

}
```

I am using the latest Firebase Android Library and running Android SDK 30.0 on Android Studio 4.0.2

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.7.1'
```

Here is an image of my code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the API for JavaScript, not Java.  Be sure to switch to the "java" tab when viewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java_10), and you will see that the API is [whereNotEqualTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereNotEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)):

```
.whereNotEqualTo("phoneNumber", currentUserPhoneCredential)
```

Comment: Thanks @Doug, I was using JS instead of Kotlin

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary to mark it correct using the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal

```
firestore.collection("Contacts").whereNotEqualTo("phoneNumber", currentUserPhoneCredential)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the API of web.
Note: For iOS, Android, and Java, the comparison operator is explicitly named in the method.

```
citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
citiesRef.whereLessThan("population", 100000)
citiesRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", "San Francisco")
citiesRef.whereNotEqualTo("capital", false)
```

So for **android java** and **android kotlin** use following code

```
firestore.collection("Contacts").whereNotEqualTo("phoneNumber", currentUserPhoneCredential)
```

for more details you can refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#kotlin+ktx_5)

Comment: Thanks @Shivam, appreciated